# How to Access Azure Table Storage using Shared Access Key in Postman?

Tags: azure, sas, postman, authorization, azure-table-storage

I use the SAS key to make a GET request for the table, but I get the error "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.". What values should I fill in on the authorization tab to work this out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8qyM.png)

x-ms-blob-type and BlobBlock work for blob storage but I need key and value for table type.

Comment: You don't need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api or BlobBlock for Table storage rest API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SAS, you don't need any API key. Set Authorization to 'Inherit Auth from Parent'.
Below are the settings I used to get my Table SAS.
[image]

And below are the settings in my Postman
[image]

The url I used for my query was `https://anumystorage.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey='A',RowKey='B')<your_sas_token>`    <-- Replace <your_sas_token> with your own Sas starting with '?sv=.....'

The information on the Table storage Rest API can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api).

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results successfully:***

I created an Azure Storage Account and created Table storage:

[image]

I generated **SAS URL** by checking the below options:

[image]

***Copy the Azure Table Storage SAS:***

[image]

To access the Azure Table Storage, include the **`Table Storage Name`** like below:

```json
https://StorageAccount.table.core.windows.net/TableStorage?TableSASUrl
```

**Response:**

[image]